# Regular expression for a username

Tags: asp.net, regex

I'm trying to write a regular expression for a username that fits the following criteria...

Must be between 6 and 16 characters,
any 4 of which must be letters (though not necessarily consecutive),
May also contain letters, numbers, dash and underscore.

So `_1Bobby1_` and `-Bo-By19-` would match, but `_-bo-_` and `-123-456_` wouldn't.

I've tried:

```
^(?=.*[a-zA-Z].{4})([a-zA-Z0-9_-]{6,16})$
```

But this doesn't seem to work, I've looked online and can't find anything that works and used Regexper to visualise the expression and try to build it from scratch.

Any pointers would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[**This**](https://regex101.com/r/bAxaV4/2/) regex can be used to verify username

```
^(?=.{6,16}$)(?=(?:.*[A-Za-z]){4})[\w-]+$
```

*Regex Breakdown*

```
^ #Start of string
(?=.{6,16}$) #There should be between 6 to 16 characters
  (?=
    (?:.*[A-Za-z]){4} # Lookahead to match 4 letter anywhere in string
  )
[\w-]+ #If above conditions are correct, match the string. It should only contain dgits, alphabets and dash
$ #End of string. Not necessary as the first check (?=.{6,16}$) itself does that
```

Comment: Works perfectly and a detailed and well explained answer.

Comment: Wasn't sure how to do it, just accepted.

Once again, thanks for that.

Answer (score 0):

```
bool IsValid(string userName)
{
    return userName.Length >= 6 && userName.Length <= 16 && userName.Count(s => char.IsLetter(s)) >= 4;
}
```

It simpler not to use regular expressions.

And as known you can use other char.Is[something] functions if you need it

Comment: This will also match usernames like `abcd__**`.. OP only wants to match alphanumeric and `-`

Comment: He can use other char.Is[Something] functions on his own

Comment: No use for client side validation, which is why I asked about regular expressions.